# Choose and locate a word in PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

This code searches helps to choose a word and locate the word in a PDF, by highlighting it, and drawing a box around it.
I found problem with the border of the rectangle, as it's thickness cannot be increased. Eventually I would like to know if the shape can be replaced with a circle/oval.

I also want to know if my code looks unreadable, I honestly feel it to be cluttered, with too much misinformation, but I have no idea what to change.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import os
import fitz
from termcolor import colored
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter 
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        self.master.title("Document Finder")

        # Create dropdown menus
        self.location_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.location_var.set("Select the Plot")
        self.location_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.location_var, "PA", "PB",command = self.update_sub_area_menu)
        self.location_dropdown.pack()
        
        self.sub_area_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.sub_area_var,"",command = self.update_level_menu)
        self.sub_area_dropdown.pack()

        self.level_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.level_var,"",command=self.update_room_menu)
        self.level_dropdown.pack()

        self.room_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.room_var.set("Select a room")
        self.room_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.room_var,"")
        self.room_dropdown.pack()

        # Create button to search for document
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Submit", command=self.handle_submit)
        self.search_button.pack()

    def update_sub_area_menu(self,selection):
        if selection == "PA":
            sub_areas = ["Basement A", "Club Lounge", "Hotel-Luxury", "Hotel-Service Apartments", "Hotel-Ultra Luxury", "Link Levels", "Others", "Penthouses", "Podium A", "Rental Offices", "Restaurants", "Spa/Gym"]
        elif selection == "PB":
            sub_areas = ["Apartments-Duplex", "Apartments-Simplex", "Basement B", "Link", "Mech & Roof", "Podium B"]
        else:
            sub_areas = []
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for sub_area in sub_areas:
            self.sub_area_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=sub_area, command=tk._setit(self.sub_area_var,sub_area,self.update_level_menu))
    
    def update_level_menu(self, selection):
        if selection == "Basement A":
            levels = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"]
        elif selection == "Club Lounge":
            levels = ["53F"]
        elif selection == "Hotel-Luxury":
            levels = ["30F", "31F", "32F", "33F", "34F", "35F", "36F", "37F", "38F", "39F", "40F", "41F", "42F", "43F", "44F"]
        elif selection == "Hotel-Service Apartments":
            levels = ["54F", "55F", "56F", "57F", "58F", "59F", "60F"]
        elif selection == "Hotel-Ultra Luxury":
            levels = ["46F", "47F", "48F", "49F","50F", "51F", "52"]
        elif selection == "Link Levels":
            levels = ["23F", "24F", "25F", "26F"]
        elif selection == "Others":
            levels = ["22F", "23F", "29F", "45F", "67F", "RF", "RF"]
        elif selection == "Penthouses":
            levels = ["61F", "62F", "63F", "64F", "65F", "66F"]
        elif selection == "Podium A":
            levels = ['GF', "1F", "2F","3F"]
        elif selection == "Rental Offices":
            levels = ["5F", "6F", "7F", "8F", "9F", "10F", "11F", "12F", "13F", "14F", "15F","16F","17F","18F","19F","20F","21F"]
        elif selection == "Restaurants":
            levels = ["4F"]
        elif selection == "Spa/Gym":
            levels = ["27F", "28F"]
        elif selection == "Apartments-Duplex":
            levels = ["30F", "31F", "32F", "33F", "34F", "35F", "36F", "37F", "38F", "39F", "40F", "41F", "42F", "43F", "44F", "45", "46F", "47F", "48F", "49F","50F", "51F", "52F", "53F", "54F","55F", "56F","57F","58F"]
        elif selection == "Apartments-Simplex":
            levels = ["5F", "6F", "7F", "8F", "9F","10F","11F","12F","13F","14F","15F","16F","17F","18F","19F","20F","21F","22F","23F","24F","25F","26F"]
        elif selection == "Basement B":
            levels = ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7"]
        elif selection == "Link":
            levels = ["28F", "29F"]
        elif selection == "Mech & Roof":
            levels = ["RF"]
        elif selection == "Podium B":
            levels = ["GF","1F","2F","4F"]
        else:
            levels = []
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for level in levels:
            self.level_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=level, command=tk._setit(self.level_var, level, self.update_room_menu))
    

    def update_room_menu(self, selection):
        if selection == "B1":
            rooms = ["FWT BA 001","FWT BA 002","RAMP 1 BA 003","MECH WATER TANK (WATER FEATURE 13) BA 004", "FIRE PUMP ROOM BA 005","VESTIBULE BA 007", "ER (ESS) BA 008","ER (NORM) BA 009","RAMP 2 BA 010","MECH LOBBY BA 012","MECH (PA FAN) BA 013","TR BA 014",
                     "MECH PUMP ROOM (WATER FEATURE 12)  BA 015","ER (ESS) BA 017","TR BA 018","ER (NORM) BA 019","BOH EV LOBBY BA 020","BOH CORRIDOR BA 021","DS BA 023","MECH (AHU ROOM) BA 024",
                     "POA BA 026","ER (HV) BA 027","OFFICE BA 028","PS (LPG) BA 029","PEA BA 030","KITCHEN BA 031","PEA BA 032","EMPLOYEE DINING BA 034","PEA BA 036","RR (M) BA 040",
                     "GOA BA 041","DIRTY LINEN STORAGE BA 042", "RR (F) BA 043","POA BA 045","JANITOR BA 050","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 051","PEA BA 052","UNIFORM ISSUE BA 054","CMA BA 055",
                     "POA BA 061","CMA BA 059","POA BA 061","OFFICE BA 062","PS (LPG) BA 063","GEA BA 064","STG BA 065","EV PIT B1F -3100 BA 066","PS BA 067","CMA BA 068","PLANT ROOM BA 069",
                     "WC BA 070","TR BA 072","SERVICE PROVIDER BA 073","PLANT ROOM BA 074","DATA CENTER BA 075","CHAUFFEUR'S LOUNGE BA 076","ER (ESS) BA 078","ER (NORM) BA 079",
                     "NOC ROOM BA 080","TR BA 081","EV PIT B1F -2600 BA 082","ELEC LEAD-IN TRENCH BA 083","LOCKER ROOM (M) BA 085","WC BA 086","GOA  BA 087","UPS ROOM BA 088",
                     "OFFICE BA 089","EV PIT B1F -700 BA 090","EV PIT B1F -700 BA 091","PA BA 092","GOA BA 093","BOH CORRIDOR BA 094","PEA BA 095","CMA BA 097","DS BA 098",
                     "POA BA 099","PA BA 101","MECH (WATER FEATURE 8,9) BA 102","DS BA 103","EV PIT B1F -700 BA 104","EV PIT B1F -700 BA 105","LOCKER ROOM (F) BA 106","MECH LOBBY BA 107",
                     "PS (OIL) BA 108","PS (PH) BA 111","IWSR BA 112","ER (NORM) BA 113","ER (ESS) BA 114","PRAYER ROOM (M) BA 115","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 116","CMA BA 117",
                     "CMA BA 118","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 119","BOH EV LOBBY BA 120","CMA BA 121","STG BA 122","PS (PH) BA 123","DS BA 124","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 126","GUEST ACTIVITIES BA 128",
                     "BGM ROOM BA 129","BOH EV LOBBY BA 130","PA BA 131","PA BA 132","PS (PH) BA 133","RESTROOM (M) BA 134","ER (ESS) BA 135","TR BA 136","SHOWER (F) BA 138",
                     "ER (NORM) BA 139","IT OFFICE BA 140","CMA BA 141","SHOWER (M) BA 142","IT EQUIP STOREROOM BA 143","RESTROOM (F) BA 144","OFFICE BA 145","FOOD & BEVERAGE BA 148",
                     "PS (HVAC) BA 149","OTB (LOADING) BA 150","STG BA 151","OTB (COMPACTOR) BA 152","CMA BA 153","OTB (FOAM TANK ROOM) BA 154","OTB (COMPOST) BA 155","PA BA 157",
                     "OTB (FUEL TANK ROOM - OFF) BA 158","VESTIBULE BA 159","TR BA 160","ER (ESS) BA 161","ER (HV) BA 162","ER (NORM) BA 163","OTB (FUEL TANK ROOM - H) BA 164",
                     "OTB (FUEL TANK ROOM - H) BA 165", "OTB (FUEL TANK ROOM - COM) BA 166", "OTB (FUEL TANK ROOM - COM) BA 167","POA BA 168","OTB (MECH - FAN ROOM) BA 169","PS (OIL) BA 171",
                     "PS (SP) BA 172","JAN BS 173","FIRST AID BA 175","STG BA 176","OFFICE BA 177","PRAYER ROOM (F) BA 178","STG BA 179","JAN BA 180","FIRST AID RECEPTION BA 181","LOCKER (F) LOBBY BA 182",
                     "STG BA 179","JAN BA 180","FIRST AID RECEPTION BA 181","LOCKER (F) LOBBY BA 182","STG BA 183","LOCKER (M) LOBBY BA 184","STG BA 185","MTG ROOM BA 186","PA BA 188",
                     "CORRIDOR BA 189","POT WASH AREA BA 191","DRY STORE BA 192","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 193","PS (ETS) BA 194","DS BA 197","CMA BA 198","COLD KITCHEN BA 199","PS BA 202","PS BA 203",
                     "PS BA 204","PS BA 205","DATA CENTER (HOTEL) BA 206","MTR BA 207","MTR BA 208","HOLDING CHILLER BA 209","CHILLER BA 210","FREEZER BA 211","SERVERY BA 212","DISH AREA BA 213",
                     "CLEAN STORE BA 214","OTB BA 215","GOA BA 216","PS BA 217","ER (HV) BA 218","PANTRY BA 219","SERVICE RAMP BA 220","BOH CORRIDOR BA 222","CMA BA 223","CMA BA 224","SE BA 225",
                     "OTB (SORTING & RECYCLING) BA 226","GOA BA 227","GEA BA 228","PS BA 229","WALKWAY BA 230","BOH CORRIDOR BA 231","EMPLOYEE DINING BA 232","MECH FAN ROOM BA 233",
                     "WATER FEATURE & PUMP ROOM BA 300","WATER BASIN (WF6) BA 037","DROP OFF BA 039","VIP WC BA 046","VIP OFFICE LOBBY BA 049","EV LOBBY BA 053","WATER BASIN (WF7) - LOBBY BA 058",
                     "EV LOBBY BA 071","EV LOBBY BA 174","VIP OFFICE PARKING BA 025","PRIVATE PARKING BA 190","PARKING (B1) BA 221","STAIR A11 BA 011","STAIR A10 BA 016","STAIR A04 BA 044",
                     "STAIR A14 BA 048","STAIR A15 BA 096","STAIR A08 BA 100","STAIR A01 BA 125","STAIR A06 BA 156"
                     ]
        elif selection == "B2":
            rooms = ["RAMP BA 001","MECH PUMP ROOM & WATER TANK (WF 14) BA 002",
                     "PS (LPG) BA 003","TR BA 005","BOH CORRIDOR BA 007","ER (ESS) BA 008","STG BA 009","ER (NORM) BA 010","RAMP 2 BA 013","BOH CORRIDOR BA 015","CMA BA 017","PS (PH) BA 018",
                     "CMA BA 019","OFFICE BA 021","STG BA 022","ER (NORM) BA 024","TR BA 025","ER (ESS) BA 026","KITCHEN SUPPORT (LAYOUT_TBD) BA 027","BOH EV LOBBY BA 028","MECH (WATER FEATURE 6,7) BA 029",
                     "DS BA 032","CMA BA 033","CMA BA 034","SAFE DEPOSIT BA 035","QUALITY BA 037","MECH ROOM BA 038","BOH CORRIDOR BA 039","ER (HV) BA 043","MECH ROOM BA 044","OFFICE BA 045",
                     "POA BA 046","CMA BA 047","PS (LPG) BA 048","MTG BA 049","STG BA 050","JANITOR BA 052","HUMAN RESOURCES BA 053","HOT KITCHEN BA 054","PS (OIL) BA 055","BOH CORRIDOR BA 056",
                     "RESERVATIONS/PBX BA 057","PEA BA 058","PA BA 060","ARCHIVE BA 061","JANITOR BA 062","PEA BA 068","RR (F) BA 069","RR (M) BA 070","CMA BA 078","RR (F) BA 079",
                     "RR (M) BA 080","STORE ROOM BA 081","PA BA 082","HEX ROOM BA 083","PA BA 084","ENGINEERING WORKSHOP BA 085","OFFICE BA 087","CMA BA 088","PS (PH) BA 089","CMA BA 090",
                     "CMA BA 091","MECH (AHU) BA 092","OFFICE BA 093","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 096","PS (ETS) BA 097","POA BA 098","ER (NORM) BA 099","ER (ESS) BA 100","FUEL TANK ROOM (COM) BA 101",
                     "STATIONARY ROOM BA 102","BEVERAGE CHILLER BA 104","GOA BA 105","HOUSE KEEPING NEW LINEN STOREROOM BA 106","FUEL TANK ROOM (COM) BA 107","FUEL TANK ROOM (H) BA 108",
                     "ER (NORM) BA 109","ER (HV) BA 110","PA BA 112","CMA BA 113","CMA BA 114","CMA BA 115","POA BA 116","BOH CORRIDOR BA 117","ER (ESS) BA 118","TR BA 120","FUEL TANK ROOM (H) BA 121",
                     "GOA BA 122","BEVERAGE CHILLER BA 123","WALKWAY BA 124","HOUSE KEEPING OFFICES BA 125","HOUSE KEEPING STOREROOM GUEST BA 126","PA BA 127","PEA BA 128","COMPOST BA 130","DS BA 132",
                     "DS BA 133","BEVERAGE STOREROOM BA 134","GEA BA 135","CMA BA 136","CMA BA 137","CMA BA 138","KEY BA 140","GEA BA 141","RAMP 3 BA 142","FOAM TANK ROOM BA 143","PS BA 144","CMA BA 145",
                     "LOADING BA 146","DRY GOODS STOREROOM BA 147","OTB (PWT/H) BA 148","PS BA 149","POA BA 150","KITCHEN CORRIDOR BA 151","EXPRESS VALET LAUNDRY BA 152","COMPACTOR BA 153","TR BA 154",
                     "PS BA 156","SORTING & RECYCLING AREA BA 157","ER (ESS) BA 158","CMA BA 159","CHILLED WASTE ROOM BA 160","SERVICE YARD BA 161","ER (NORM) BA 163","OTB (EV PIT) BA 164","EV PIT ABOVE BA 165",
                     "TR BA 166","EXPRESS VALET OFFICE BA 167","EXPRESS VALET STG BA 168","MAIN WASTE ROOM BA 169","GOA BA 170","CMA BA 171","SE BA 172","EV PIT ABOVE BA 173","BIN WASHING AREA BA 174",
                     "HAZARDOUS WASTE AREA BA 175","EV PIT ABOVE BA 176","BOH EV LOBBY BA 177","CMA BA 178","BOH EV LOBBY BA 179","P03 EV PIT BA 181","PA BA 182","GOA BA 183","TROLLEY/CRATE WASHING AREA BA 185",
                     "DRY GOODS STOREROOM BA 186","CHEMICAL STOREROOM BA 187","AMENITIES STOREROOM BA 188","PEA BA 189","CMA BA 190","POA BA 191","BOH CORRIDOR BA 192","STAGING AREA BA 193","SERVICE YEAR DOCK BA 194",
                     "CMA BA 195", "EV PIT ABOVE BA 196","EV PIT ABOVE BA 197","POA BA 199","MECH BA 200","ER (ESS) BA 201","ER (NORM) BA 202","STAGING AREA BA 203","ER (NORM) BA 205","TR BA 207",
                     "MECH (LAUNDRY AHU) BA 208","HOTEL SECURITY BA 209","PS (SP) BA 210","RECEIVNG OFFICE BA 212","CMA BA 213","BOH EV LOBBY BA 215","CMA BA 216","CMA BA 217","CMA BA 219","LOADING DOCK BA 220","FLORIST ROOM BA 223",
                     "FIRE EV LOBBY BA 224","FIRST AID BA 225","BOH CORRIDOR BA 227","WC BA 228","PS (PH) BA 229","PS (HVAC) BA 231","OTB BA 232","USED CHARCOAL AND ASHES BA 233","ER (ESS) BA 234",
                     "TR BA 235","FM SECURITY BA 236","SE BA 237","GENERAL FREEZER BA 238","ENGINEERING OFFICE BA 239","STORE ROOM BA 240","FUEL TANK ROOM (OFF) BA 241","BULK WASTE AREA BA 242",
                     "EXECUTIVE & ASSISTANT CHEF'S OFFICE BA 243","PORK KITCHEN BA 244","SOU CHEF'S OFFICE BA 245","STEWARDING OFFICE BA 246","CELEBRITY CHEF HOLDING CHILLER 1 BA 247",
                     "OPERATION STOREROOM BA 248","CMA BA 249","CHILLER BA 250","CHILLER BA 251","FREEZER BA 252","CHILLER BA 253","FRUIT & AMENITIES COLD KITCHEN BA 254",
                     "BULK KITCHEN  BA 255","HOT KITCHEN BA 256","SEAFOOD PRE-CUT HOLDING BA 257","MEAT PRE-CUT HOLDING BA 258","SEAFOOD PREP BA 259","MEAT PREP BA 260","SEAFOOD CHILLER BA 261",
                     "MEAT CHILLER BA 264","POULTRY FREEZER BA 265","POULTRY CHILLER BA 266","POULTRY PREP BA 267","POULTRY PRE-CUT HOLDING BA 268","BLAST FREEZER BA 269","LOGISTICS BA 270",
                     "POT WASH STEWARDING BA 271","CLEAN STORE BA 272","DAIRY & JUICES CHILLER BA 273","PRE-CUT HOLDING CHILLER BA 274","VEGETABLE PREP BA 275","CHILLER BA 276","SANITIZATION BA 277",
                     "DEBOXING BA 278","FREEZER BA 279","HOLDING CHILLER BA 280","STORE BA 281","DISPATCH FRUITS & AMENITIES HOLDING CHILLER BA 282","BAKERY CHILLER BA 283","BAKERY FREEZER BA 284",
                     "PASTRY FREEZER BA 286","PASTRY CHILLER BA 287","BAKERY/PASTRY AREA BA 287","CHEF OFFICE BA 288","DRY STORE BA 289","CHILLER BA 290","ICECREAM BA 291","CAKE ROOM BA 292",
                     "CHOCOLATE ROOM BA 291","POT WASH BA 294","KITCHEN CORRIDOR BA 295","PS BA 296","PS BA 297","KITCHEN CORRIDOR BA 298","CELEBRITY CHEF HOLDING CHILLER 2,3,4 BA 299",
                     "PS (OIL) BA 300","ER (HV) BA 301","BOH CORRIDOR BA 302","BOH CORRIDOR BA 303","SERVICE RAMP BA 304","GOA BA 305","GEA BA 306","DISH WASH AREA BA 307","ORDER TAKER BA 308",
                     "ROOM SERVICE BA 309","STORE BA 310","STORE BA 311","CHILLER BA 312","THAWING CHILLER BA 313","KITCHEN SUPPORT BA 314","TROLLEY PARKING BA 218","STAIR A11 BA 012","STAIR A10 BA 023",
                     "STAIR A04 BA 111","STAIR A06 BA 129","STAIR A14 BA 131","STAIR A08 BA 184","STAIR A01 BA 222"]
        elif selection == "B3":
            rooms = ["TR BA 001","ER (ESS) BA 011","ER (NORM) BA 003","WALKWAY BA 005","GOA BA 007",
                     "WALKWAY BA 005","ER (ESS) BA 011","BOH EV LOBBY BA 012","TR BA 013","RAMP 1 BA 014","DS BA 015","POA BA 016","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 017","PEA BA 018","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 019",
                     "MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 020","PEA BA 021","STG BA 022","PS (PH) BA 023","PS (ETS) BA 024","GOA BA 026","STG BA 027",'PA BA 029',"POA BA 030","PEA BA 032","DS BA 034","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 035",
                     "GEA BA 036","OTB (PWT/H) BA 037","PEA BA 039","STG BA 040","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 041","POA BA 042","PS BA 043","OTB (PWT/H) BA 044","PUMP ROOM 1 BA 045","TR BA 046",
                     "ER (ESS) BA 047","ER (NORM) BA 049","OTB (EV PIT) BA 050","GOA BA 051","PEA BA 052","OTB (PWT/H) BA 053","PA BA 054","GOA BA 055","POA BA 056","OTB (PWT/H) BA 058",
                     "MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 059","POA BA 060","RAMP 2 BA 061","ER (ESS) BA 063","TR BA 064","ER (NORM) BA 065","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 066","BOH EV LOBBY BA 067","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 068",
                     "T11 EV PIT BA 070","PEA BA 071","PA BA 072","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 073","PS (HVAC) BA 074","PEA BA 075","PS (PH) BA 076","PS (PH) BA 077","EV PIT ABOVE BA 078","PA BA 079",
                     "STG BA 083","BOH EV LOBBY BA 084","STG BA 086","STG BA 087","STG BA 088","PA BA 089","TR BA 091","WALKWAY BA 092","ER (ESS) BA 093","ER (NORM) BA 094","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 095",
                     "POA BA 096","POA BA 097","STG BA 098"," MECH PUMP ROOM (WATER FEATURE 13) BA 099","DS BA 101","PEA BA 102","PEA BA 103","PA BA 104","POA BA 105","STG BA 106","ENGINEERING STOREROOM BA 110",
                     "MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 112","STG BA 113","RAMP 3 BA 114","GOA BA 115","PUMP ROOM 2 BA 116","PUMP VALET OFFICE BA 118","EV LOBBY BA 033","VIP EV LOBBY BA 048","EV LOBBY BA 033","VIP EV LOBBY BA 048",
                     "EV LOBBY BA 080","VIP WAITING AREA BA 117","PARKING (B3) BA 025","STAIR A11 BA 004","STAIR A10 BA 009","STAIR A04 BA 028","STAIR A08 BA 057","STAIR A01 BA 069","STAIR A06 BA 090"]
        elif selection == "B4":
            rooms = ["TR BA 001","ER (ESS) BA 002","ER (NORM) BA 009","ER (ESS) BA 010","BOH EV LOBBY BA 012","TR BA 013","DS BA 014","POA BA 015","POA BA 016","PEA BA 017","STG BA 018","PS (PH) BA 019",
                     "PS (ETS) BA 020","GOA BA 022","STG BA 024","PA BA 025","POA BA 026","GEA BA 028","DS BA 030","PUMP ROOM 1 BA 031","PWT (H) BA 032",'PEA BA 034',"STG BA 035","PS BA 036","PWT (H) BA 037",
                     "TR BA 038",'ER (ESS) BA 039',"STG BA 040","PS BA 036","PWT (H) BA 037",'TR BA 038',"ER (ESS) BA 039","STG BA 040","ER (NORM) BA 041","EV PIT BA 042","GOA BA 043",'PEA BA 044',"PWT (H) BA 045",
                     "PA BA 046","GOA BA 047","POA BA 048","PWT (H) BA 045","PA BA 046","GOA BA 047","POA BA 048","PWT (H) BA 050","POA BA 051","ER (NORM) BA 052","ER (ESS) BA 054","TR BA 055","STG BA 057",
                     "STG BA 058","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 059","BOH EV LOBBY BA 060","EV PIT ABOVE BA 062","PEA BA 063","PEA BA 064","PS (HVAC) BA 065","PS (PH) BA 066","PEA BA 067","PA BA 068","PA BA 069",
                     "STG BA 073","BOH EV LOBBY BA 074","STG BA 076","STG BA 077","STG BA 078","PA BA 080","WALKWAY BA 081","ER (ESS) BA 082","TR BA 083","ER (NORM) BA 084","POA BA 085","POA BA 086",
                     "STG BA 087","DS BA 091","RAMP 1 BA 092","RAMP 2 BA 093","PS (PH) BA 094","STG BA 095","STG BA 096","PS (PH) BA 097","STG BA 098","PA BA 099","STG BA 100","STG BA 101","GOA BA 102",
                     "EV LOBBY BA 029","EV LOBBY BA 071","PARKING (B4) BA 021","STAIR A11 BA 004","STAIR A10 BA 008","STAIR A04 BA 023","STAIR A08 BA 049","STAIR A01 BA 061",'STAIR A06 BA 079']
        elif selection == "B5":
            rooms = ["TR BA 001","ER (ESS) BA 002","ER (NORM) BA 003","WALKWAY BA 005","GOA BA 007","ER (NORM) BA 009","ER (ESS) BA 010","BOH EV LOBBY BA 013","TR BA 014","DS BA 015","POA BA 016","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 017","PEA BA 018","STG BA 019","PS (PH) BA 020",
                     "PS (ETS) BA 021","GOA BA 022","STG BA 023","PA BA 025","POA BA 026","GEA BA 028","DS BA 030","PUMP ROOM 1 BA 031","PEA BA 033","STG BA 034","PWT (LL) BA 035","PS BA 036",
                     "TR BA 037","ER (ESS) BA 038","ER (NORM) BA 039","STG BA 040","PWT (LL) BA 041","GOA BA 042","PEA BA 043","PWT (LL) BA 044","PA BA 045","GOA BA 046","POA BA 048","PWT (LL) BA 049",
                     "POA BA 050","ER (NORM) BA 053","ER (ESS) BA 054","TR BA 055","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 056","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 057","BOH EV LOBBY BA 058","PEA BA 059","JANITOR BA 061","PS (PH) BA 063",
                     "PS (HVAC) BA 064","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 065","PEA BA 067","DS BA 070","STG BA 071","BOH EV LOBBY BA 072","STG BA 075","STG BA 076","STG BA 077","PA BA 079","WALKWAY BA 080","ER (ESS) BA 081",
                     "TR BA 082","ER (NORM) BA 083","POA BA 084","MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 085","POA BA 086","STG BA 087","RAMP 1 BA 088","RAMP 2 BA 089","PA BA 090","PA BA 091","PS (PH) BA 092","PS (PH) BA 093",
                     "PEA BA 094","PA BA 095","STG BA 096","PS (PH) BA 097","STG BA 098","STG BA 099","STG BA 101","STG BA 103","GOA BA 104","EV LOBBY BA 029","EV LOBBY BA 069","PARKING (B5) BA 011",
                     "STAIR A11 BA 004","STAIR A10 BA 008","STAIR A04 BA 024","STAIR A08 BA 047","STAIR A01 BA 060","STAIR A06 BA 078"]
        elif selection == "B6":
            rooms = ["TR BA 001","ER (ESS) BA 002","ER (NORM) BA 003","WALKWAY BA 005","GOA BA 006","ER (NORM) BA 008","ER (ESS) BA 009","BOH EV LOBBY BA 010",'PA BA 011',"TR BA 012",
                     "DS BA 013",'POA BA 014',"PEA BA 015","STG BA 016","STG BA 018","PA BA 020","POA BA 021","WALKWAY BA 022","PUMP ROOM 1 BA 024","GEA BA 025","DS BA 028","STG BA 030",
                     "PEA BA 031","PS BA 032","TSE BA 033","TR BA 034","GREASE TRAP ROOM BA 035","ER (ESS) BA 036","TSE BA 040","PA BA 041","GOA BA 042","OTB (MECH PUMP ROOM 2) BA 043",
                     "POA BA 044","TSE BA 046","PA BA 049","ER (ESS) BA 050","TR BA 051","ER (NORM) BA 052","BOH EV LOBBY BA 053","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 054","JANITOR BA 055","OTB (PS-ETS) BA 057",
                     "PS (PH) BA 058","PS (HVAC) BA 059","PEA BA 060","BOH EV LOBBY BA 063",'FIRE EV LOBBY BA 054',"JANITOR BA 055","OTB (PS-ETS) BA 057","PS (PH) BA 058","PS (HVAC) BA 059","PEA BA 060","BOH EV LOBBY BA 063",
                     "OTB (ETS) BA 064","OTB (MECH PUMP ROOM 1) BA 066","OTB (MECH) BA 067","WALKWAY BA 068","STG BA 070","STG BA 071",'STG BA 072',"PA BA 074","WALKWAY BA 075","TR BA 076","ER (NORM) BA 077",
                     "ER (ESS) BA 078","POA BA 079","POA BA 080","STG BA 081","GOA BA 083","OTB (FWT) BA 084","OTB (FWT) BA 085","DS BA 088","RAMP 2 BA 089","RAMP 1 BA 090","PA BA 901","PEA BA 092",
                     "PS (PH) BA 093","PS (PH) BA 094","PS (ETS) BA 095","PS (PH) BA 096","PS (PH) BA 097","STG BA 098","STG BA 099","STG BA 100","STG BA 101","GOA BA 103","EV LOBBY BA 027","EV LOBBY BA 062",
                     "PARKING (B6) BA 017","STAIR A11 BA 004","STAIR A10 BA 007","STAIR A04 BA 019","STAIR A08 BA 045","STAIR A01 BA 056","STAIR A06 BA 073"]
        elif selection == "B7":
            rooms = ["TR BA 001","STG BA 002","ER (ESS) BA 003","ER (NORM) BA 004","WALKWAY BA 006","GOA BA 007","PA BA 008","STG BA 010","ER (NORM) BA 011","P04 EV PIT BA 012","ER (ESS) BA 013",
                         "BOH EV LOBBY BA 014","TR BA 015","DS BA 016","POA BA 017","PEA BA 018","PEA BA 019","STG BA 020","RAMP 2 BA 021","GOA BA 022","STG BA 023","POA BA 025","WALKWAY BA 026",
                         "P02 EV PIT BA 027","GEA BA 029","PUMP ROOM 1 BA 030","DS BA 032","PA BA 033","P02 EV PIT BA 034","STG BA 035","PEA BA 036","PS BA 037","PUMP ROOM 2 BA 038","TR BA 039",
                         "ER (ESS) BA 040","ER (NORM) BA 041","FWT BA 042","MECH PUMP ROOM 1 BA 043","GOA BA 044","PUMP ROOM 3 BA 045","GOA BA 046","POA BA 047","T13 EV PIT BA 049","TR BA 050",
                         "PUMP ROOM 4 BA 051","ER (ESS) BA 052","ER (NORM) BA 053","FIRE EV LOBBY BA 054","BOH EV LOBBY BA 055","JANITOR BA 057","PS (HVAC) BA 058","PS (PH) BA 059","PS (ETS) BA 060",
                         "PEA BA 061","STG BA 062","P12 EV PIT BA 063","BOH EV LOBBY BA 065","P01 EV PIT BA 066","STG BA 067","STG BA 068","STG BA 069","WALKWAY BA 071","TR BA 072","ER (ESS) BA 073",
                         "ER (NORM) BA 074","POA BA 075","POA BA 076","STG BA 077","MECH PUMP ROOM 2 BA 078","FIRE PUMP ROOM BA 079","MECH BA 080","ETS BA 081","VESTIBULE BA 082","T12 EV PIT BA 083",
                         "DS BA 084","PA BA 085","PS (PH) BA 086","RAMP 1 BA 087","PA BA 088","PA BA 089","PA BA 090","PS (PH) BA 091","PS (PH) BA 092","FWT BA 093",'GSM ROOM BA 094',"PS (PH) BA 097",
                         "STG BA 098","STG BA 099","GOA BA 100","EV PIT BA 197","EMPOWER CTRL RM BA 198","EV LOBBY BA 031","EV LOBBY BA 064","PARKING (B7) BA 028",'STAIR A11 BA 005',"STAIR A10 BA 009",
                         "STAIR A04 BA 024","STAIR A01 BA 056","STAIR A06 BA 070"]

        elif selection == "53F":
            rooms = ["BOH CORRIDOR TA 003","BOH CORRIDOR TA 007","ER (ESS) TA 008","ER (NORM) TA 009","FIRE EV LOBBY TA 010","BOH EV LOBBY TA 011","PA TA 012","PA TA 017","PS TA 018",
                     "PS TA 019","PS TA 020","PS TA 021","PS TA 022","PS TA 025","PS HVAC TA 027","PS TA 029","PS TA 030","PS TA 031","CMA TA 033","TR TA 034","PS PLMG TA 035",
                     "BOH LUGGAGE TA 036","PS TA 037","PS TA 039","PS TA 040","ER TA 041","AMENITIES TA 061","OFFICE/STORE TA 062","ORDER TAKER TA 063","ROOM SERVICE TA 064","FREEZER TA 065",
                     "CHILLER TA 066","DISH POT WASHA AREA TA 067","CLEAN STORE TA 068","HOT KITCHEN TA 069","COLD KITCHEN TA 070","PASTRY AREA TA 071","BEVERAGE CHILLER TA 072","ICE STATION TA 073",
                     "BEVERAGE STORE TA 074","BEVERAGE DISPENSE TA 075","CLUB LOUNGE TA 014","EV LOBBY TA 026","PRIVATE CORRIDOR TA 042","RECEPTION TA 043","EV LOBBY TA 050","PRIVATE ROOM TA 080",
                     "DINING AREA TA 081","COLD COUNTER TA 082","PANTRY TA 083","LOUNGE TA 084","BAR TA 085","ADA TA 086","TOILET F TA 087","TOILET M TA 088","PANTRY TA 089","BARISTA COUNTER TA 090",
                     "CAVIAR TA 091","STAIR A01 TA 001","STAIR A02 TA 002"]
        elif selection == "30F":
            rooms = ["LINEN WC TA 007","ER (ESS) TA 008","ER (NORM) TA 009","FIRE EV LOBBY TA 010","BOH EV LOBBY TA 011","PA TA 012","CORRIDOR TA 014","IWSR TA 015","PA TA 017",
                     "PS TA 019","PS TA 020","PS TA 021","PS TA 022","CMA TA 023","PA TA 025","PS HVAC TA 027","PS TA 029","PS TA 030","PS TA 031","CMA TA 033","TR TA 034","PS PLMG TA 035",
                     "PS TA 037","PS TA 039","PS TA 040","PS TA 041","PS TA 042","DIRTY LINEN TA 051","HK PANTRY TA 052","HK LINEN STORE TA 053","CORRIDOR LUXURY HOTEL TA 003","EV LOBBY TA 026",
                     "STD CORRIDOR TA 091","STD CORRIDOR TA 092","PILATES STUDIO TA 151","YOGA AREA TA 152","PANTRY TA 153","CONSULTANT ROOM TA 154","GYMNASIUM TA 155","POWER ROOM 1 TA 156",
                     "POWER ROOM 2 TA 157","FREE WEIGHT & STRENGTH ROOM TA 158","STORE TA 159","STORE TA 160","CORRIDOR TA 161","GR 3 3001","GR 4 3002","GR 2 3003","GR 1.3 3004","GR 1.2 3005",
                     "GR 1.2 3006","GR 1.2 3007"
                     ]
            
   
        else:
            rooms = []
        self.room_var.set("Select the room")
        self.room_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for room in rooms:
            self.room_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=room, command=tk._setit(self.room_var, room))


    def find_document(self):
        # Construct the file path based on the selected room and level
        file_path = f"C:/Users/hexapod/stuff/drawinglochighlighter/dropdown/OZ31317-ZL0100-DWG-{self.location_var.get()}-{self.level_var.get()}.pdf"
        # Check if the file exists in the directory
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
        # Open the file using PyMuPDF
            return fitz.open(file_path)
    
        #Function to highlight text in PDF
    def highlight_text(self, pdf_file, room_id):
        for page in pdf_file:
            ### SEARCH
            text = str(room_id)
            print(text)
            split_text = text.split()
            word = " ".join(split_text[-2:])
            print(word)
            text_instances = page.search_for(word)

            ### HIGHLIGHT
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                highlight.set_colors({"stroke":(0, 1, 0), "thickness": 2})  # <-- change thickness here
                highlight.update()

                ### RECTANGLE
                bbox = fitz.Rect(text_instances[0].tl.x - 80, text_instances[0].tl.y - 80, text_instances[-1].br.x + 80, text_instances[-1].br.y + 80)
                rect = page.add_rect_annot(bbox)
                rect.set_colors({"stroke": None, "fill":None}) # <-- change thickness here
                rect.update()
                
                # Add a white rectangle with desired opacity on top of the green rectangle
                yellow_bbox = fitz.Rect(bbox.tl.x + 3, bbox.tl.y + 3, bbox.br.x - 3, bbox.br.y - 3, )
                yellow_rect = page.add_rect_annot(yellow_bbox)
                yellow_rect.set_colors(stroke=None, fill=(1, 1, 0))
                yellow_rect.set_opacity(0.34)
                yellow_rect.border_width = 0
                yellow_rect.update()

                print(highlight)  
                print(yellow_rect)
                print(rect)

            ### OUTPUT
            pdf_file.save("highlighted.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)

    def handle_submit(self):
        #
        room_type = self.room_var.get()
        pdf_file = self.find_document()
        if pdf_file:
            self.highlight_text(pdf_file, room_type)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Text highlighted in PDF!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","PDF File not found for selected space ID")

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you include full code (`rooms = [...]`)

Comment: The endless `if` / `elif` style can be fixed with a `dict`, e.g. in `update_sub_area_menu` assign `sub_areas = self._selection_to_subarea.get(selection, [])`. Define the mapping at class level, with 2-char strings mapping to lists. Notice that we default to empty list if selection was not "PA" or "PB". Maybe that data belongs in your source code, or maybe you'd find it more convenient to read it from a .CSV file. The `for` loop in `highlight_text` would benefit from Extract Helper Method, but otherwise things look nice enough.

Comment: @J_H I would really like to find a solution to draw an ellipse.

Comment: The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. I've modified the title accordingly. Your request to modify the box into an ellipse is technically off-topic, since that's a feature request and not a request for review. However, should an answerer choose to do so, they might as well help make the code more re-usable to support either.

Comment: There is a lot of `rooms = [...]` going on in your code, but inconsistently. Is this your actual code or did you cut parts out of it?

Comment: I had cut parts of it.

Comment: I can't run your code. The [docs](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.add_circle_annot) seem to explain pretty clearly what you want. The same doc page has `draw_circle` (which can produce an ellipse) and `add_polygon_annot`, as well, so you could even build a curved line from many small line segments if you like. There's copious examples in their tutorial section. Add the function call and let us know what technical details were needed to make it work.

Comment: [Relevant question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75637286/1014587) by same author.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 4):

> I also want to know if my code looks unreadable, I honestly feel it to be cluttered, with too much misinformation, but I have no idea what to change.

Your code contains too much data. It's fine to have a few constants, but for your code it's the majority.

Instead, you could add a `selection2rooms.json` and a `selection2levels.json`

Then remove unused imports, remove unnecessary comments, and apply [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff/):

```
ruff check --select=ALL --fix codereview.py
```

and it looks a lot better:

```py
import json
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import fitz


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        self.master.title("Document Finder")

        # Create dropdown menus
        self.location_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.location_var.set("Select the Plot")
        self.location_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.location_var, "PA", "PB",command = self.update_sub_area_menu)
        self.location_dropdown.pack()

        self.sub_area_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.sub_area_var,"",command = self.update_level_menu)
        self.sub_area_dropdown.pack()

        self.level_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.level_var,"",command=self.update_room_menu)
        self.level_dropdown.pack()

        self.room_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.room_var.set("Select a room")
        self.room_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.room_var,"")
        self.room_dropdown.pack()

        # Create button to search for document
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Submit", command=self.handle_submit)
        self.search_button.pack()

    def update_sub_area_menu(self,selection):
        if selection == "PA":
            sub_areas = ["Basement A", "Club Lounge", "Hotel-Luxury", "Hotel-Service Apartments", "Hotel-Ultra Luxury", "Link Levels", "Others", "Penthouses", "Podium A", "Rental Offices", "Restaurants", "Spa/Gym"]
        elif selection == "PB":
            sub_areas = ["Apartments-Duplex", "Apartments-Simplex", "Basement B", "Link", "Mech & Roof", "Podium B"]
        else:
            sub_areas = []
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown["menu"].delete(0, "end")
        for sub_area in sub_areas:
            self.sub_area_dropdown["menu"].add_command(label=sub_area, command=tk._setit(self.sub_area_var,sub_area,self.update_level_menu))

    def update_level_menu(self, selection):
        with open("selection2levels.json") as f:
            selection2levels = json.load(f)
        levels = selection2levels.get(selection, [])
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown["menu"].delete(0, "end")
        for level in levels:
            self.level_dropdown["menu"].add_command(label=level, command=tk._setit(self.level_var, level, self.update_room_menu))


    def update_room_menu(self, selection):
        with open("selection2rooms.json") as f:
            selection2rooms = json.load(f)
        rooms = selection2rooms.get(selection, [])
        self.room_var.set("Select the room")
        self.room_dropdown["menu"].delete(0, "end")
        for room in rooms:
            self.room_dropdown["menu"].add_command(label=room, command=tk._setit(self.room_var, room))


    def find_document(self):
        # Construct the file path based on the selected room and level
        file_path = f"C:/Users/hexapod/stuff/drawinglochighlighter/dropdown/OZ31317-ZL0100-DWG-{self.location_var.get()}-{self.level_var.get()}.pdf"
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            return fitz.open(file_path)

    def highlight_text(self, pdf_file, room_id):
        for page in pdf_file:
            text = str(room_id)
            split_text = text.split()
            word = " ".join(split_text[-2:])
            text_instances = page.search_for(word)

            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                highlight.set_colors({"stroke":(0, 1, 0), "thickness": 2})
                highlight.update()

                ### RECTANGLE
                bbox = fitz.Rect(text_instances[0].tl.x - 80, text_instances[0].tl.y - 80, text_instances[-1].br.x + 80, text_instances[-1].br.y + 80)
                rect = page.add_rect_annot(bbox)
                rect.set_colors({"stroke": None, "fill":None}) # <-- change thickness here
                rect.update()

                # Add a white rectangle with desired opacity on top of the green rectangle
                yellow_bbox = fitz.Rect(bbox.tl.x + 3, bbox.tl.y + 3, bbox.br.x - 3, bbox.br.y - 3 )
                yellow_rect = page.add_rect_annot(yellow_bbox)
                yellow_rect.set_colors(stroke=None, fill=(1, 1, 0))
                yellow_rect.set_opacity(0.34)
                yellow_rect.border_width = 0
                yellow_rect.update()

            pdf_file.save("highlighted.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)

    def handle_submit(self):
        room_type = self.room_var.get()
        pdf_file = self.find_document()
        if pdf_file:
            self.highlight_text(pdf_file, room_type)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Text highlighted in PDF!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","PDF File not found for selected space ID")


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```